# custom deserializing a date with format

Tags: java, jackson

> ["last_modified"])] with root cause
>   java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-06-06T13:19:53+00:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19

The inbound format is `2018-06-06T13:19:53+00:00`
It's a weird format.

I have tried the following:

```
public class XYZ {  
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00", iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from creating your own deserializer. A very naive example could be the following:

```
public class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    private static final String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+00:00";

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public LocalDateTimeDeserializer() {
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTERN);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(p.getText(), formatter);
    }
}
```

The only thing you need to notice is that you'll need to escape the 'T' by adding single quote around it.

With the deserializer in place you can simply annotate the field like so:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

Comment: tried a few of the answers, this one worked the best.

Answer (score 1):

> The inbound format is `2018-06-06T13:19:53+00:00`
> It's a weird format.

That's the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which is endorsed by the [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) and by the [xkcd 1179](https://xkcd.com/1179/):

[image: xkcd 1179: ISO 8601]

---

The following should work as expected when receiving the values as query parameters:

```java
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private LocalDate dateTime;
```

As `2018-06-06T13:19:53+00:00` represents a date and time with an offset from UTC, you'd better use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) rather than [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

```java
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private OffsetDateTime dateTime;
```

Just ensure that `+` is encoded as `%2B`.

---

With Jackson, you could add the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency to your application. This module will provide you with [serializers](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/package-summary.html) and [deserializers](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/package-summary.html) for [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) types.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And then register the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) module in your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Jackson will handle the serialization and deserialization for you.

If you are, for some reason, not interested in the offset from UTC and want to keep using [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), you could extend the [`LocalDateTimeDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/LocalDateTimeDeserializer.html) provided by Jackson and use a custom [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```java
public class CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends LocalDateTimeDeserializer {

    public CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer() {
        super(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    }
}
```

Then annotate the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) field as shown below:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The inbound format is 2018-06-06T13:19:53+00:00

If you're able to set the Date Format on your entire ObjectMapper, you could do the following:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
objectMapper.setDateFormat(df);
```

This is part of the examples from the [SimpleDateFormat Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)